# Image Source not found or ContentDescription is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imagebutton

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/wallhaven_263366"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imagebutton" />
```

this is my code.. and I tried almost every thing I found here...

I've added the image in src but its not showing in either preview or avd. some times it give error of not found src as given

or content description missing.. if I provide a content description and res value then it says could not resolve resource @string/.

any sort of help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Missing content description is not an error.

If you sure the file is in the Drawablr folders try to reneame it and remove the digits. SOmetimes it cause problems when using digits in file name.

Comment: I did erased the digits and now 

       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
       > Crunching Cruncher wallhaven.png failed, see logs


this is the new error

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting Ctrl + F9 if you are operating over windows, this will build the project. I have faced similar errors while starting up the studio and after building the project it solves them. And even try removing the extra digits from image name.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Abhinav\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Error:(18, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/wallhaven_263366').



getting these errors while trying to build

Answer (score 0):

Solution :Just edited the image  format to png through paint .. earlier I did by renaming it in directory.

//other problem
but still idk why none of the button or image is visible in avd yet I can add remove or edit them in preview mode.

P.S.

they are also not visible in preview just editable